# Como deixar a última coluna fixa com scroolbar horizontal?

Tags: html5, bootstrap-3, table, bootgrid

Estou usando um simples plugin: http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/

Como eu posso deixar última coluna fixada ?

Aqui tem um exemplo de uma coluna fixada: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html

Estou tentando deixa a última coluna fixado, porem nada certo. Segue o código em jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30996/

Segue o código:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="grid-command-buttons" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped bootgrid-table" aria-busy="false">

...

  </table>
</div>
```

Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu usei css para tentar congelar essa última coluna. Para isso, criei as seguintes classes:

```
.bootgrid-wrapper {
  width: 90%; // 100% menos o tamanho da ".fixed-column-right"
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.fixed-column-right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  right: 0;
}
```

Daí na sua `<div>` onde está a `<table>` dentro, você adiciona a primeira classe `bootgrid-wrapper`:

```
<div class="table-responsive bootgrid-wrapper">
  <table id="grid-command-buttons" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped bootgrid-table" aria-busy="false">
    ...
  </table
</div>
```

...e depois precisa adicionar a classe `fixed-column-right` na `<th>` e na `<td>` da última coluna. No caso do bootgrid, isso é feito adicionando dois atributos na `<th>`:

- `data-header-css-class="fixed-column-right"`: o bootgrid irá adicionar na classe da própria `<th>`
- `data-css-class="fixed-column-right"`: o bootgrid irá adicionar na classe de cada `<td>` dessa coluna.

> Tentar adicionar diretamente o atributo `class="alguma-classe"`  na `<td>` ou na `<th>` nao vai funcionar, pois quando o bootgrid é montado, ele recria tudo, excluindo seus atributos.

---

No final, seu **HTML** completo fica assim:

```
<div class="table-responsive bootgrid-wrapper">
  <table id="grid-command-buttons" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped bootgrid-table" aria-busy="false">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-column-id="id" data-identifier="true" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
        <th data-column-id="sender">Sender</th>
        <th data-column-id="received" data-order="desc">Received</th>
        <th data-column-id="sender1">Sender</th>
        <th data-column-id="sender2">Sender</th>
        <th data-column-id="sender3">Sender</th>
        <th data-column-id="sender4">Sender</th>
        <th data-column-id="sender5">Sender</th>
        <th data-column-id="sender6">Sender</th>
        <th data-column-id="sender7">Sender</th>
        <th data-column-id="sender8">Sender</th>
        <th data-column-id="sender9">Sender</th>
        <th data-column-id="received" data-order="desc">Received</th>
        <th data-column-id="commands" data-header-css-class="fixed-column-right" data-css-class="fixed-column-right" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Coluna</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Segue seu [JSFiddle atualizado](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/33028/).